# Unexpected TextBox Control actions in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to dynamically draw textbox controls in a windows form and I successfully getting it to draw the textboxes but with unexpected behavior. It supposed to draw 2 textboxes based on the 3 elements its getting from an XML file, it does this. However the resulting text in the textbox is messed up. It cuts off characters and wont let me scroll through the string with arrow keys on the keyboard. It also wont let me go to the start or end of the string. The output is:

[image]

The code I am using is:

```
    NameValueCollection DatabaseConnectionList = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("databaseTypes") as NameValueCollection;
    int x = 80;
    int y = 70;
    for (int i = 0; i < DatabaseConnectionList.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox T2 = new TextBox();
        T2.Text = DatabaseConnectionList.Get(i);
        T2.Size = new Size(200, 20);
        T2.Location = new Point(x, y);

        this.Controls.Add(T2);
        y += 25;
    }
```

I don't see anything wrong with the code but maybe I am missing something that gives it the same functionality as if I just draw the control using Visual studio.

Edit:
The XML section is:

```
  <databaseTypes>
    <add key="ExampleServerPrefix_T" value="Connection_String_For_ExampleServer" />
    <add key="ExampleServer2Prefix_T" value="Connection_String_For_ExampleServer_2" />
    <add key="COPYLIVE_" value="ODBC;DSN=rrrr;DATABASE=yyy;SERVER=xxxxxx;PORT=5432;" />
  </databaseTypes>
```

Comment: There's nothing obvious wrong, care to share (parts of the) the XML, too?

Comment: Yes I will add it in now but I don't see how this is the issue because `DatabaseConnectionList` is just a collection.

Comment: Well, above code works.

Comment: Something different is at work here. The code is correct and also if the Get could be blamed if some part of the strings are missing there is nothing here that stops the editing. So, where do you call this code? Do you have threads or some kind of loop around here that blocks the editing?

Comment: The code is being called in the form initializer. The only things above the code in the question is `public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); NameValueCollection...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments; posted code works just fine.

Using simple `App.config` and the code provided

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="databaseTypes" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </configSections>
    <databaseTypes>
      <add key="ExampleServerPrefix_T" value="Connection_String_For_ExampleServer" />
      <add key="ExampleServer2Prefix_T" value="Connection_String_For_ExampleServer_2" />
      <add key="COPYLIVE_" value="ODBC;DSN=rrrr;DATABASE=yyy;SERVER=xxxxxx;PORT=5432;" />
    </databaseTypes>
</configuration>
```

Result is below. Just as you would expect, chars are not "cut off" (except for too short control width) and selecting/scrolling content is just fine.

[image]

I think you might be "swallowing" the keydown/keypress events somewhere? Don't know but one thing I do know: This code has nothing in it producing the effects you described.

Comment: I am using an App.config and in the exact same way as you have in your answer. I don't know why the TextBoxes are doing what they are doing. It is strange. It is also hard to describe what exactly is going on. I can post the entire method if this helps?

Comment: No, I will be trying this on a different machine tomorrow just to see maybe something was just messing up because as you say the code is fine. I will be in touch.

Comment: Well... How did it go?

Comment: Not exactly sure still why it was not working but I got it to work on a different machine.